# SQL to ACCESS 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I imported my SQL information into Access. How can I create a table in Access, then join or link it to an existing table already in Access 2010.

Comment: Do you want to link to an already existing table within the same Access database?  Are you wanting to link to another table in another database?  This is a bit vague

Answer (score 0):

I just use 'Access Data Projects' (ADP). This allows me to keep everything on the SQL Server side, and it allows me to write stored procedures (and bind them to forms, etc) without writing mountains of linked table / SQL passthrough code.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to set up a UNION query. That will leave your two tables intact but join the data.

A JOIN query would merge the data into one of the existing tables.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins post has some good info about that.